# search for only particular value in a map

Tags: java, groovy

I have the file in below format :

```
name = David 
city = tokyo
Asia.COuntry.origin = Japan
name = mia 
city = kuala lampur
SouthAsia.COuntry.origin = malaysia
name = bilal 
city = karachi
NorthAsia.COuntry.origin = pakistan
name = Murphy 
city = london
europe.COuntry.origin = england
```

I have written below code to make a map of the above file :

```
def File = new File("C:/Users/.................")
def Prop = new Properties()
File.withInputStream { stream ->
    Prop.load(stream)
}
```

Now using variables as Key , I am able to fetch value from the above map as follows :

```
{  "$Prop.'Asia.COuntry.origin'}"
```

**Problem:** The value is not static in the above file and any no of persons may be included in the above file and so I cannot pass "KEY" to fetch the value of cOuntry.origin . **Is there a way to search for those keys which have "country.origin" appended at the tail and search for all keys containing "country.origin" and pass key one by one as I am doing above .**

Comment: Who comes up with data like that? Might be worthwile to fix the data first before tryting to bend over to make them work.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily search for all entries where the key ends with `COuntry.origin` and process them, but I don't think your approach is correct anyway. In a `Properties` file you can have each key only once.

Or rather you can have it multiple times, but only the last line with the key is considered and overwrites the former lines. So in your end result you will only have one entry for `name` and one entry for `city`.

I think you should change your file reading to not use `Properties`, but do custom parsing like `new File(...).readLines()` and then transforming the lines into the data structure you need.

Comment: Thanks for the input . I agree that each key is unique . For time being I can pass each key and extract the value . No problem . But later on the properties get updated and a new “country.origin” may come up . Then I don’t want to manually go to my code and pass the key again . So I am trying to write something which will fetch every key with “country.origin” in it .

Comment: You mean like `Prop.findAll { key, value -> key.endsWith '.COuntry.origin' }`?

Comment: Yeah that is the logic basically

Comment: And that was the answer. That was no pseudo-code, but exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Get it . Thanks a ton .

Comment: When I run this code :def Files = new File("C:/Users/........")
def Props = new Properties()
Files.withInputStream { stream ->
 Props.load(stream)
}
Props.findAll { key, value -> key.endsWith '.COuntry.origin' }
println(Props)

Comment: I get this as output : [europe.COuntry.origin:england, SouthAsia.COuntry.origin:malaysia, NorthAsia.COuntry.origin:pakistan, name:Murphy , Asia.COuntry.origin:Japan, city:london]

Comment: I cant get it why I am getting name and city as key:value here

Comment: Because you print the original `Map`, not the result of the `findAll` method. If you do either `println Props.findAll { key, value -> key.endsWith '.COuntry.origin' }` or `Props = Props.findAll { key, value -> key.endsWith '.COuntry.origin' }; println Props` it works.

Answer (score 1):

Though not efficient, one option is to write a `DynamicProps` class that loads the properties each time:

```
class DynamicProps {
    def props 
    def file = new File('data.properties')

    def getKeys(def suffix) {
        def results = []
        props = new Properties()
        file.withInputStream { stream ->
            props.load(stream)
        }
        def allKeys = props.propertyNames()

        while (allKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
            def key = allKeys.nextElement()
            if (key ==~ ".*${suffix}") {
                results << key 
            }
        }

        results
    }
}

// -- main

def dynamicProps = new DynamicProps()
println dynamicProps.getKeys(".COuntry.origin")
```

Comment: I tried to run your code like this :def props
def file = new File("C:/Users/......................")

def suffix= "COuntry.origin"
def getKeys(suffix) {
 def results = []
 props = new Properties()
 file.withInputStream { stream ->
  props.load(stream)
 }
 def allKeys = props.propertyNames()

 while (allKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
  def key = allKeys.nextElement()
  if (key ==~ ".*${suffix}") {
   results << key
  }
 }

 results
}

Comment: Problem is that the error is same as in below @Vampire's code : I am getting same issue where I have the name and city in output of the last person of the above  input file : [europe.COuntry.origin:england, SouthAsia.COuntry.origin:malaysia, NorthAsia.COuntry.origin:pakistan, name:Murphy , Asia.COuntry.origin:Japan, city:london]

Answer (score 1):

Following @Vampire's suggestion, this code will process the file into a Map of properties by region.

```
def data = [:]
def props = [:]
new File(/C:\Users\................./).eachLine { line ->
    def (name, value) = line.split('=').collect { it.trim() }
    if (name.endsWith('COuntry.origin')) {
        def region = name.split(/\./)[0]
        props['country'] = value  // or whichever key you want
        data[region] = props.clone()
        props.clear()
    } else {
        props[name] = value
    }
}
```

With the resulting `data` Map, you can get all of the regions using the `keySet()` method

```
assert data.keySet().containsAll(['Asia', 'SouthAsia', 'NorthAsia', 'europe'])
```

And for a given region, you can get the name, city, and country as follows:

```
assert data['Asia'] == [name: 'David', city: 'tokyo', country: 'Japan']
```

Comment: I really appreciate the input , but I am looking for the keys with '.COuntry.origin' at the tail end . your code will give me what is prepend in '.COuntry.origin'

Comment: it contains both. If by "keys" you mean the values of the ".COuntry.origin" properties, it's  `data.values()*.country`

Comment: I am not looking for the value of the keys . I am looking for just the keys such as Asia.COuntry.origin , SouthAsia.COuntry.origin ,..... i.e any key with  "COuntry.origin" in it .

Comment: Such that in the loop or if statement I will pass the variable and whatever key has "COuntry.origin" in it , each one I can pass rather than hardcode the keys each time as {  "$Prop.'Asia.COuntry.origin'}" , ..................

Comment: `data.keySet()` gives you that. If you really need the ".COuntry.origin" suffix, just append it again: `data.keySet().collect { "${it}.COuntry.origin" }`